# Не могу подключить слот к сигналу QDbus

Tags: qt5, connect

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QDBusConnection>
#include <QDebug>

class Window: public QWidget
{
public:
    Window(){}

    void slot(QString str, QVariantMap map, QStringList list)
    {
        qDebug() << str << map << list;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Window *win = new Window();
    QDBusConnection con = QDBusConnection::sessionBus();
    bool result = con.connect("org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.chromium.instance14494",
                              "/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2",
                              "org.freedesktop.Properties",
                              "PropertiesChanged", win, SLOT(slot(QString, QVariantMap, QStringList)));
    qDebug() << result;
    return app.exec();
}
```

При запуске программы с QDBUS_DEBUG=1

Я получаю следующее:

```
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x7fb450003a00) : connected successfully
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x7fb450003a00) got message (signal): QDBusMessage(type=Signal, service="org.freedesktop.DBus", path="/org/freedesktop/DBus", interface="org.freedesktop.DBus", member="NameAcquired", signature="s", contents=(":1.1735") )
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x7fb450003a00) delivery is suspended
false
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x7fb450003a00) dequeueing message QDBusMessage(type=Signal, service="org.freedesktop.DBus", path="/org/freedesktop/DBus", interface="org.freedesktop.DBus", member="NameAcquired", signature="s", contents=(":1.1735") )
```

При переключении музыкального трека в браузере, вывод в терминале не меняется, по dbus-monitor видно, как дёргается сигнал PropertiesChanged.

Так же я знаю что у `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.chromium.instance14494` после перезапуска хромиума меняются на конце цифры, пробовал с vlc, результат один и тот же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Команда `dbus-monitor --session | grep MediaPlayer2 -A10`  мне не выдаёт в поле `sender` `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.chromium.instance14493` (в моём случае), хотя `qdbusviewer` его отображает. Зато в этом поле присутствует значение `:1.157`:

```
signal time=1615138292.971503 sender=:1.157 -> destination=(null destination) serial=154 path=/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=PropertiesChanged
   string "org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "PlaybackStatus"
         variant             string "Playing"
      )
   ]
   array [
   ]
```

Поменяв код на

```
bool result = con.connect(":1.157",
                          "/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2",
                          "org.freedesktop.Properties",
                          "PropertiesChanged", win, SLOT(slot(QString, QVariantMap, QStringList)));
```

должно в `result` вернуть `true` и в слот прилетать:

```
"org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player" QMap(("PlaybackStatus", QVariant(QString, "Playing"))) ()
"org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player" QMap(("PlaybackStatus", QVariant(QString, "Paused"))) ()
```

Тестировал на [вот этих](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8Kr_aFB6Ww) ребятах в хромиуме.

**dbuslistener.h**

```
#ifndef DBUSLISTENER_H
#define DBUSLISTENER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QVariantMap>

class DbusListener : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DbusListener(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

signals:

public slots:
    void slot(QString s, QVariantMap m, QStringList l);

};

#endif // DBUSLISTENER_H
```

**dbuslistener.cpp**

```
#include "dbuslistener.h"
#include <QDBusConnection>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDBusError>

DbusListener::
DbusListener(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    QDBusConnection con = QDBusConnection::sessionBus();
    if(!con.isConnected()) {
        qFatal("Bus error");
    }

    qDebug() << con.connect(":1.264",
                "/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2",
                "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
                "PropertiesChanged",
                this,
                SLOT(slot(QString, QVariantMap, QStringList)));
}

void DbusListener::slot(QString s, QVariantMap m, QStringList l)
{
    qDebug() << "SIGNAL" << s << m << l;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "dbuslistener.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    DbusListener dbs;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: [В dbus-monitor](https://dpaste.com/8QG5EACQ7.txt), в коде изменил `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.chromium.instance14494` на `:1.11`, [выхлоп](https://dpaste.com/56LQBPLA6.txt) программы изменился, в `result` так же `true` и слот по прежнему не вызывается.

Comment: @Олег я создал отдельный класс со слотом, в конструкторе которого вызывал код выше. Работало, попробуйте тоже вынести.

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы имели в виду [это](https://dpaste.com/3HSV56BC5.txt), извините, если не так понял. Но при таком варианте у меня в `result` попадает `false`, в слот так же ничего не прилетает. Вы можете показать свой код?

Comment: @Олег добавил код

Comment: Я сравнил ваш и свой код, и увидел что у вас `"org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"`, а у меня `"org.freedesktop.Properties"`
Исправил это в своём коде, пересобрал проект и всё заработало. Большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так попробуйте:

```
class Window: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT // + макрос
public:
    Window(){}

public slots: // + slots
    void slot(QString str, QVariantMap map, QStringList list) {
        qDebug() << str << map << list;
    }
};

int main(...) {
    ...
}

// + Так как Q_OBJECT класс находится в одном файле с main.cpp, то надо подключить 
// мос-файл для нормальной сборки проекта
#include "main.moc";
```

Comment: Я сделал как вы сказали, вывод в терминале изменился, но при переключении музыки в браузере, вывода от слота не наблюдаю.
Вот вывод, который я наблюдаю на данный момент: https://dpaste.com/2A7FBG5FJ.txt

Comment: @Олег попробуйте очистить проект и пересобрать. Если не поможет, то проблема в чем-то другом

Comment: Я отчистил и пересобрал, не помогло.